# Difference in cookie content using Sinatra session & Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie

Tags: ruby, cookies, sinatra, session-cookies, rack

I'm learning Sinatra framework & developing a login system. I came across  two ways of using cookies.

A simple Sinatra inbuilt way:

```
enable :sessions
set :session_secret, 'random-key'
```

This approach produces following cookie content while logged in (used `session.inspect` to get the output):

```
{"session_id"=>"6be0b9a31831604ba51114d265ba952482e0b2da6ced6c54e15ebe7f212858ca", 
"tracking"=>{"HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"b8c1e8f89eeaea0b825bed0d811f0c7678e98c74", 
"HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"=>"a0bfc876d68fe7aea700da5ea8925abac6f2f794", 
"HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"dd065ed263c67d799f943ab6c39b55c5e008cbb5"}, 
"csrf"=>"b480324f510e4f391d15cee8236a8fb74a5aaa5ce2f9ad38e4dbb025a823b16e",    
"name"=>"john"}
```

Another approach is using an encrypted cookie :

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'encrypted_cookie'

use Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie, :secret => "random-key"
```

But this approach produces following cookie content while logged in (used `session.inspect` here too):

```
{:name=>"john"}
```

Why `enable :sessions` is creating such a big cookie with all that information & why is it required (especially those HTTP_... parts?) Because `Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie` isn't generating any of it.

Do you think that using `enable :sessions` should be preferred because it has csrf token & session id? Or do you think that `Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie` is enough since it is encrypted?

I have following versions of gems installed :

```
encrypted_cookie (0.0.4)
rack (1.5.2)
rack_csrf (2.4.0)
sinatra (1.4.3)
thin (1.5.1)
```

Please tell me if you need more information...

Answer (score 1):

Because Sinatra will use [`rack-protection`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra) middleware when you enable `:sessions`. It makes cookie bigger but more secure.

Relevant snippet:

```
def setup_default_middleware(builder)
  builder.use ExtendedRack
  builder.use ShowExceptions       if show_exceptions?
  builder.use Rack::MethodOverride if method_override?
  builder.use Rack::Head
  setup_logging    builder
  setup_sessions   builder
  setup_protection builder
end

def setup_sessions(builder)
  return unless sessions?
  options = {}
  options[:secret] = session_secret if session_secret?
  options.merge! sessions.to_hash if sessions.respond_to? :to_hash
  builder.use session_store, options
end

def setup_protection(builder)
  return unless protection?
  options = Hash === protection ? protection.dup : {}
  options = {
    img_src:  "'self' data:",
    font_src: "'self'"
  }.merge options

  protect_session = options.fetch(:session) { sessions? }
  options[:without_session] = !protect_session

  options[:reaction] ||= :drop_session

  builder.use Rack::Protection, options
end
```

- `sessions?` returns true if you enable :sessions
- `session_store` is `Rack::Session::Cookie` by default

The difference between `Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie`

That is, if you want to use `Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie` with `rack-production`, it can be easily done by:

```
enable :sessions
set :session_store, Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie
```

FYI, since [encrypted_cookie](https://github.com/cvonkleist/encrypted_cookie) is lack of some features (secret rotation, custom serializer, etc) and no longer under maintenance, I made [**another one**](https://github.com/tonytonyjan/rack_encrypted_cookie) to replace it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie` requires that your secret be at least 16 bits long. In the README, they recommend using OpenSSL for generating the secret, like so:

```
ruby -ropenssl -e "puts OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(16).inspect"
```

If you open your inspector, you'll see a cookie named 'rack.session', and its contents obfuscated.

Comment: Yea. I know that :). But my question is would you prefer `enable :sessions` because it is producing session id & csrf token & all that extra stuff? or would you prefer `Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie` because its encrypted & doesnt need those additions?

Comment: Are you using any other middleware? Doing `enable :sessions` and then inspecting the session gives me an output similar to that of `Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie`. Personally, I use `Rack::Session::Cookie` as middleware and set the secret on that (loaded from an environment variable).

Comment: Hmmm. While using `enable :sessions` approach, I'm not using any other middleware. BTW, I edited the question to include versions of required gems. I may have different version of some gem compared to you. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, when using Rack::Session::Cookie in Sinatra, and write session_secret as an environment variable, the session which has created won't destroy after the project deploy. I think this is a risk in Single Page Application.